# Calling AppEngine from Firebase Functions

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase

I couldn't find any resource about how to call an App Engine Service from a 
Firebase function
I know I could call it by the URL but in that case it would be an external call and it would apply charges to it.

Besides in every video they say it's posible to access Google API's
Did I understand it bad or there is a API call for App Engine?

Thanks!

Comment: this might help, but this is storage related: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the App Engine service *internally*, through the private network of your Google Cloud Project. Only specific Products are interconnected in your Virtual Private Cloud, as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#vpc_networks_and_subnets).

The API for App Engine can have two meanings:

1. The [Google App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/) - this allows you to manage your App Engine deployments programmatically through a REST API service. All the interactions available through the Console (web browser), and maybe more, are available through these API endpoints. Google's [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/app%20engine/appengine/v1/) is a tool which brings together all available API endpoints for Google services.
2. You can enable [your own API endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) for the services that you have deployed in your App Engine - this time it is you who defines what will the actual endpoints be and how requests to that endpoints are treated (i.e. by your App Engine app). These are **still external** calls between Firebase and App Engine. They will go through the Internet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. One question, in your link AppEngine Flex is included (and this is my case). Where can I find documentation on how to make a call through the subnet? if it is possible at all. Thanks!

Comment: There is [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings) on how to configure the network where the AppEngine VMs will reside. But you will not be able to access the App Engine API internally, from Cloud Functions. The internally connected products are the ones mentioned in the first link in my answer. Can you please provide more details on what you attempt to do?

Comment: Hi, thank for your time. I have a nodejs app that access Cloud Sql, which is not available on cloud functions (yet), I use app engine to expose a REST Api, simple http requests. But I understand in the documentation that it can't go through the private network, which sounds strange to me. That's the main question, do I have to pay those calls as if they were to the open Internet or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi @ElBarto,
[App Engine Flexible with Node js and Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql) documentation. [Ingress to Cloud SQL is free of charge, and egress to Google Compute Engine instances in the same region is free](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-storage-networking-prices). Also, there is no charge for accessing  Google APIs at *.googleapis.com [from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#other-resources).
If my answer(s) is solving your question(s), please accept it.

Comment: Of course, you can always estimate your costs, using [the Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

Comment: HI @Tudormi, Thanks for your answers, but the links you are given me are about calling CloudSQL within AppEngine. My question is about calling AppEngine within CloudFunctions on the private network. If there's no way, I accept it. But I just wanted to check it before assume it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the heads-up. There's no way to call App Engine from Cloud Functions via the internal network. I suppose there could be different architecture implementation for your case... like using [microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#app_engine_services_as_microservices). Maybe you can simulate the costs pretty well to have an idea about what would be the optimal solution.